# Error while assigning Users to an Organization: com.liferay.portal.NoSuchResourceActionException

Tags: liferay

I am getting following error while assiging users to organization using `UserServiceUtil.addOrganizationUsers(orgId, userIds)`

```
ERROR [AdvancedPermissionChecker:944]
   com.liferay.portal.NoSuchResourceActionException: 
      com.liferay.portal.model.Organization#ASSIGN_MEMBERS
```

I guess I need to add a row in Resource Table with `com.liferay.portal.model.Organization` name and `ASSIGN_MEMBERS` in actionID. But what to insert in `resourceActionId` and `bitwiseValue` fields.

or Is there any other way to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about what you are trying to do? Like are you executing the call in a hook, plugin-portlet or ext-plugin?

This permission is already present in Liferay for Organization and you can check the `portal.xml` file in the location [`portal-impl/src/resource-ations/portal.xml`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/resource-actions/portal.xml) the permission is denoted as [`<action-key>ASSIGN_MEMBERS</action-key>`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/resource-actions/portal.xml#L475).

Comment: Also you can update what version of liferay you are using and other relevant stuff to the problem. Do you get this error when you assign members through the liferay UI interface in the control panel?

Comment: I am using it in plugin-portlet and I am using Liferay v6.1.0 CE

Comment: Have you done any changes to the permissions or roles in your custom portlet through resource-actions or something. Coz I didn't find any problem with my custom portlet calling this and other methods. You can also try undeploying and then re-deploying your portlet. If need be restart the server after cleanly undeploying your portlet.

Comment: No, I haven't changed any permissions or roles . and I redeployed the portlet , but same error appeared . By the way there is also another error  com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException

Comment: Do you have a hook or ext also deployed on the same bundle?

Comment: no .. UserLocalServiceUtil.addOrganizationUsers(orgId, userIds) is working fine but UserServiceUtil.addOrganizationUsers(orgId, userIds) is throwing the error

Comment: There is similar kind of issue here - [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15610519) , it says this is bug. But how to be sure ?

Comment: In ResourceAction table of liferay , there is no corresponding table entry for ASSIGN_MEMBERS

Comment: It was a bug in 5.2.3 but not in Liferay 6.1.1, ok do one thing empty your database or create a new database and point liferay to the fresh database. As far as I see in my clean installation this permission exists in `ResourceAction` table like this `112 ----com.liferay.portal.model.Organization ---- ASSIGN_MEMBERS ---- 2`

Comment: To be sure it is not a bug: 1) Clean Database 2) Take fresh installation of Liferay 3) Point to the clean Database 3) Start the server 4) Check if all the database tables are created with the records and then check if this record is present in the `ResourceAction` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fresh installation of Liferay 6.1.1 ga 2 resolved this issue for me.